# Save edited video with python CV2

Tags: python, opencv, video

I'm using the following code to create a video with rectangles in all its frames. However, the video is not being saved after it is created. How can I edit the code to have the video save in one of my folders.

```
 import cv2

 #Reads the video and collects it information
 cap = cv2.VideoCapture('20150326_060700_062957_themis_rank_fisheye.mp4')
 fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
 width  = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)   # float
 height = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)  # float
 output = cv2.VideoWriter("output.mp4", -1, fps,(int(width),int(height)))

while (cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

       if (ret):

       # Adds the rectangles in all frames
        rect1 = cv2.rectangle(frame, (135, 510), (200,450), (255, 0, 0), 1)
        rect2 = cv2.rectangle(frame, (365, 365), (430, 430), (255, 0, 0),1)
    
        # writing the new frame in output
        output.write(frame)
        cv2.imshow("output", frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('s'):
          break
  else:
     break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()  
output.release()  
cap.release()
```

Comment: if file gives image with `width, height` different then you want to save then you have to `resize()` frame before save

Comment: do you get error or empty file? We can't read in your mind - you have to add all details in question (not in comments)

Comment: frist put code with correct indentations because code with wrong indentations is useless. We can't run it, and maybe all your problem is some wrong indentation - but we can't see it.

Comment: you may have to set codec manually instead of `-1`. Code doesn't create file for me if I use `-1` but I get file when I use `cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP4V')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code creates file for me when I set manually codec instead of `-1`

```
#fourcc = -1
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP4V')
output = cv2.VideoWriter("output.mp4", fourcc, fps,(int(width),int(height)))
```

I never saw code with `-1`. Maybe it doesn't work.

Comment: Amazing! this actually worked. Thank you!